# How to store QR codes in rails generated from rqrcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, qr-code, carrierwave

I need to generate a QR code and store it in rails. I am using [rqrcode gem](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode) for generating QR code.

Here is how I am generating QR code as png.

```
  def generate_qr_code(checkin_url)
    qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(checkin_url)
    png = qrcode.as_png(
      bit_depth: 1,
      border_modules: 4,
      color_mode: ChunkyPNG::COLOR_GRAYSCALE,
      color: 'black',
      file: nil,
      fill: 'white',
      module_px_size: 6,
      resize_exactly_to: false,
      resize_gte_to: false,
      size: 120
    )
    self.update!(qr_code_image: png.to_s)
  end
```

**Issue:**
I am facing issues while storing the QR code in `qr_code_image`.

`self.update!(qr_code_image: png.to_s)` showing following error:

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `map' for #<String:0x007feb358121d0>
Did you mean?  tap
```

Even `IO.write("/tmp/github-qrcode.png", png.to_s)` showing

```
*** Encoding::UndefinedConversionError Exception: "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I finally have to store the png image in `qr_code_image` where I am using

```
mount_uploaders :qr_code_image, QrCodeUploader
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `png.to_s` return a binary content of file

To write a file from a binary contente run:

```
File.binwrite("/tmp/github-qrcode.png", png.to_s)
```

If you want save a png.to_s on your database, I think that use a base64 is a good choice.

To save a base64 in your model the code is something like that

```
u = User.find(1)
u.qr_code_image = Base64.encode64(png.to_s)
u.save
```

Finaly, to see a qrcode in browser just

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= user.qr_code_image %>" />
```

Comment: I am using `mount_uploaders :qr_code_image, QrCodeUploader` where I need to store qr codes on s3 bucket. I do not need base64 because of some limitations.

Comment: @UzairNadeem I recommend wearing [Active Storage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)

Comment: @UzairNadeem did you found solution for it? I'm going through same issue.

Comment: You just saved my life.. Thank you